# Rad Menu and Div Issue

Tags: watir

one more problem... i have an application which have a rad menu telerik menu... and it is placed in a DIV as shown below.
e.g.

```
DIV class = RadMenu RadMenu_Hay id = ctl00_RadMenu UL class = rmHorizontal rmRootGroup  L1 class = rmItem rmFirst Aclass = rmlink rmfirst Span class = rmtext #text...
```

i just want to know, how i use the div in watir to select menu and submenu both...any help in this regard will highly be appreciated...on internet i didnt find any specific example .. so help me out..

```
div class= RadMenu RadMenu_hay id='ctl00_RadMenu'
        ul class rmHorizontal rmRootGroup
           lI class = rmItem rmFirst
               A class=rmLinkrmFocused
                   SPAN class = rmtext
```

Comment: You will have to post relevant HTML, and explain what you want to do with it.

Comment: If the menus are produced by javascript or something like that, selecting the first menu item expands a submenu, then you may have the submenu "disappear" as the mouse pointer travels to the submenu item to click. I had a problem like that before, which was solved by injecting a javascript call that was triggered by the submenu selection. Or maybe I am way off on your goal & problem - in which  case Zeljko's suggestion would help.

Comment: Please ask your developers specifically which version of the Telerik tools they are using.  Then pick the appropriate demo version from http://www.telerik.com/support/demos/developer-tools-demos.aspx and find the instance of the control you are trying to manipulate.  Edit your question and insert a link to the proper demo page, add an annotated screenshot if needed to make it clear.  Once people here have an example of the control to experiment with, it becomes FAR easier to give you a good answer, including working code sample for controlling the demo control.

Comment: i m unable to add screenshot in the question... message promote "you are not an old user..."secondly its a mouse hover event..hierarchy of that menu is look like this..charting-> add patient so when user mouse hover that charting text a sub menu will display...and then user can select its required result...we are using telerik Q3 2008 version controls...

Comment: i have added the html code in my question.

Comment: What do you want to do? Click the `span` element?

Comment: no i want to select the text that is displaying under the span class as shown in the above code...and this control used the mouse hover property..

Comment: Main Menu
   - Sub Menu... i want to select the 'submenu' text and it's displaying on mouse hover event.

Comment: OK so you are using older controls, that may not be a problem in terms of the demo site if they have not changed how that control works.  We'd still need to know which flavor, eg. Ajax, WPF, Winforms, etc..

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this from IRB to see if it makes the menu open

browser.div(:id, 'ctl00_RadMenu').fire_event 'onmouseover'

if it does then you should then be able to do click on the appropriate link (most likely selecting by the text in the link.)  You will also likely have to put a sleep of a second or so after the mouseover to give the client side code time to render the menu and get the objects inside it into a state where they can be seen and clicked.

Without seeing actual full real HTML I can't be sure.  And without access to a site actually running that control there's no way for us to test it to be sure..